# How to read /dev/mem using read()

Tags: c, mmap, pci-e

I am trying to read some physical address that is mapped to PCIe device using /dev/mem. The PCIe device is mapped to `0x387ffa000000`:

```
bash# lspci -s 1a:00.0 -v | grep Memory
      Memory at 387ffa000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
```

So I wrote some program that's based on what I found here at SO which makes use of [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)():

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <phys_addr> <offset>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    off_t offset = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    size_t len = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    size_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    off_t page_base = (offset / pagesize) * pagesize;
    off_t page_offset = offset - page_base;

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Can't open");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char *mem = mmap(NULL, page_offset + len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, page_base);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Can't map memory");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)  printf("%02x ", (int)mem[page_offset + i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Although this works:

```
bash# ./mem_read.out 0x387ffa000000 0x10
00 1f 00 18 00 05 07 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I wanted to try the same only with [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)()/[write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)() calls instead of mmap().
But when I tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <phys_addr> <size>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    off_t offset = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    size_t len   = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    if (!len) {
        printf("size argument can't be 0\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Can't open");
        return 1;
    }

    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
        perror("Can't seek");
        return 1;
    }

    char* buff = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (read(fd, buff, len) < 0) {
        perror("Can't read");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

It fails with:

```
bash# ./mem_read.out 0x387ffa000000 0x10
Can't read: Bad address
```

That same code works when instead of `/dev/mem` I use a regular text file.
Does anyone have an idea why the former works but the latter does not?

Just for additional context, "Bad address" is printed when `errno == EFAULT`, which returned by `read()` when:

> buf is outside your accessible address space.

which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Please don't use externally-hosted images to show text. Copy/paste the text *into the question*, where we can see it.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have the kernel option `CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM` set?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for the `/dev/mem` device, it seems to [check](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.8/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L123) that the address is a valid physical address.

Comment: OK, I see that in the `valid_phys_addr_range()` check it says in comment: 
`/* Can we access it for direct reading/writing? Must be RAM: */`
In my case, the address isn't mapped to RAM but rather to I/O...

Answer (score 0):

Read function callback in driver check for valid address, and return `EFAULT` if address was not valid.

As stated in Commit message when this function `valid_phys_addr_range()` was added in the kernel.

> x86 does not define ARCH_HAS_VALID_PHYS_ADDR_RANGE, which
> leads /dev/mem to use the default valid_phys_addr_range()
> and valid_mmap_phys_addr_range() in drivers/char/mem.c.
>
> The default valid_phys_addr_range() allows any range lower than
> __pa(high_memory), which is the end of system RAM, and disallows any range higher than it.

How `read()` behaves on other architectures I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Read `syscall` callback in  /dev/mem driver check for valid physical address is below `high_memory` in `valid_phys_addr_range()` and return with `errno`  EFAULT if address was not valid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).